# Is it possible to have different return in the same function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have that function :

```
def choice(default=True):
    if default:    
        return 1
    else:
        return 0, "Your choice is 0"
```

In the first case I get one variable, in the second case I get two variables.

Is it a problem to do that in Python ? I tested and it works, but for instance in c++ that kind of things does not work. Do you know if there is a rule about that such as PEP8 or something like that ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: It is purely bad code. Why would you want to do that? It is because you return either int or int and string.

Comment: It is possible, but I would consider it bad practice, since the caller will have to protect against unexpected return values.

Comment: this is what pep8 says about return : """Be consistent in return statements. Either all return statements in a function should return an expression, or none of them should. If any return statement returns an expression, any return statements where no value is returned should explicitly state this as return None, and an explicit return statement should be present at the end of the function (if reachable):"""

Comment: You could at least have the first be `return 1, None`

Comment: @schwobaseggl How can it be "unexpected" if the caller has to pass an option to toggle between the return values?

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa That seems just an example. Imagine more complex logic. After all, the OP inquires about the principle in general.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely fine to have a function with different return value signatures, depending on the options passed. See [`np.unique` for example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). Since Python does not have function overloading, this is the canonical way of achieving that. The important point is to document it properly. In the example of `np.unique` you'd otherwise have to define eight different versions of the function with all combinations of return values. Impractical, hard to maintain, and mostly redundant.

Another way to handle this kind of "function overloading" in Python is to always use the same return value signature, but return `None` for unused values. I like the former method better.

Comment: One can argue that np.unique is simply badly designed. Which I fully agree with. Just because someone does this doesn't mean it is good.

Comment: @freakish The alternative is to have eight different functions with all possible combinations of return values: `np.unique_return_inverse`, `np.unique_return_index_counts` and so on. Like I said, if one is pedantic about maintining the return value signature, there are ways to achieve that, but why?

Comment: That's not a bad alternative. But ther's better: the return type could be a custom object with all that data inside with None (or some other indicator) when not queried for. The reason we are pedantic about return types is because we don't want to change the code (after call) only because we changed arguments. Also it is easier to do to static analysis, which in Python is alraedy difficult by design.

Comment: The "custom object" you describe can be a `tuple`, and that's what Python returns when you return multiple objects from a function. I stated that as a possible alternative in the answer. ;-)

In the case of `unique` you *want* to have a different result, that's the whole point of the extra return option. It does not make sense to keep the old code because you explicitely ask for a semantically different thing. It's not too hard to replace your old `uniq = np.unqiue(a)` calls with `uniq, inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)`.

Comment: Yes, it can be a `tuple` if it is used consistently, in every case. No, in case of `np.unique` the person that designed the function wants to have a different result based on arguments. I don't want that, I'm not sure what you mean by "you", who exactly are you referring to? And yes, it is not too hard to do pretty much anything in programming. Yet, contrary to what you believe, an inexeprienced coder won't change this line until the code fails at production. Yes, static analysis, design pattern, good practices, and so on, exist only to avoid human mistakes.

Comment: The *you* I mention is a person using `np.unique`. If you want to get the inverse values in addition for example, you'd have to change the line of code anyway, regardless whether you use `uniq, inv = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)` or `uniq, inv = np.unique_return_inverse(a)`.

Comment: I can imagine that the `np.unique_return_inverse(a)` version is better suited for static code analysis, though.

Answer (score 1):

> In the first case I get one variable, in the second case I get two variables.

Actually in both cases you get a single object. In the first case it is an int, and in the second case it is a tuple (with int and string inside).

> Is it a problem to do that in Python ?

Technically? No. In terms of maintenance and readability? Yes. Can you imagine someone's surprise when he realizes that changing an argument changes the type of the result (in your case int vs tuple)? What's worse these types are completely unrelated. Typically noone will expect that. And then they have to write weird logic to handle it. Annoying.

Also how would you document this function? The return type is inconsistent, unless you simply say "it returns an object" which is too general to be useful.

Finally such design will likely confuse any static code analysis. And we want static analysis to reduce human errors.

> I tested and it works, but for instance in c++ that kind of things does not work.

It does work in C++ as well (and probably in any language), although in a bit different way. After all what Python returns is "an object", it is up to the caller to interpret that. It is very similar to return `void*` from a C++ function and force the caller to do appropriate cast. Which is a very bad practice as well. Even worse in C++, since it is strongly typed.

> Do you know if there is a rule about that such as PEP8 or something like that ?

Well, not explicitly about this situation, but "PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code" does say "Be consistent in return statements.".